# One page won't show on wordpress after moving from live to localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, permalinks

I moved my website from live to localhost to make some modifications to it and I have encountered a problem, one page will not show up: "Oops! That page can’t be found.".

I have tried the following
1. activated rewrite_module
2. deactivated each plugin to see if anyone is causing the problem
 
3. recopied the database and files in case of failure during the first transfer
4. read that resetting permalinks might solve the problem. Changed permalinks to default - the page now works, but when I changed back to custom the problem is still there.

This is weird because only one page does not seem to show, every other page works fine and also there is no problem on the live version.

I ran out of solutions can any one please help?

Comment: did you try to go to settings->permalinks and click save?

Comment: @Nick Surmanidze Yes, I did. Forgot to mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be caused by the permalink or .htaccess

check the url of your page if no issues on URL then

**Follow this steps once:**

1. Go to settings-> permalink-> set it as default ->Reload or refresh
2. Then again now Go to settings-> permalink->postname

Your .htaccess will get update with the permalink.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with htaccess. When using the query string urls in wordpress, no htaccess is required, but for anything else Wordpress uses mod_rewrite.

Is htaccess turned on your localhost Apache server? In httpd.conf, `AllowOverride All` should be turned on in your active directory.

Is Wordpress able to create new files? Insufficient permissions might prevent it from creating the htaccess file.

Finally, check that your links are pointing to the right place. Sometimes the problem is as simple as a misspelling in your link ;) Good luck.

Comment: I checked for misspellings, no problem there, I changed allowoveride to all and the problem is still there. As for the htaccess and permissions, I don't know what I am supposed to do. The only thing I tried is to remove htaccess and that did not work and I don't know how to grant permission to wordpress n localhost

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making the changes to httpd.conf?

Comment: When you solve it, be sure to post a solution. I'm curious!

Comment: Got it. Check the answer above